# Android: how to draw TextView as focused?

Tags: android

I have a series of Views in a tablelayout.  Some are EditTexts, some are TextViews. I would like the TextViews to be focusable in the same way as the EditTexts; meaning, I would like them to be highlighted by the "up" and "down" arrows.  `TextView.setFocusable(true)` allows them to gain focus from arrow keys, but they do not draw an orange border to indicate their focus like the EditTexts do.  Is there an easy way to draw them as focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector as your textColor and/or background and give it different states for state_focused="true" and state_focused="false".

[Color State List Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: Thanks. Any idea of a good way to set the background? I copied the file "list_selector_background_focus.9.png" into my project. And set it as the drawable in the selector.  But, it does not properly stretch to fill my TextView.

Comment: @ab11 Is your TextView set to wrap_content on it's width?